# How can I make a variable that counts instances in multiple other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have this dataset:

```
nhhmembers <- c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 5)
hhmember1 <- c(1994, 2020, 1943, 1946, 1970, 1989)
hhmember2 <- c(NA, 2000, 1950, 1970, 1969, 1980)
hhmember3 <- c(NA, 1990, NA, 1999, 2011, 2014)
hhmember4 <- c(NA, 1975, NA, 1989, NA, 2018)
hhmember5 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1997, NA, 2015)

df <- data.frame(nhhmembers , hhmember1, hhmember2, hhmember3, hhmember4, hhmember5)
```

I want to create a new variable nkids that counts through hhmember1-5 for all the years makes the age (2021 minus hhmemberx) less than 18.

So nkids should be 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3 in this case

I can't quite figure out the best way to do this without making a very long case_when.

Comment: I think you'd be best to convert to long format, calculate age and then summarise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R one-liner:

```r
rowSums(2021 - df[-1] < 18, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 3
```

Comment: Does this look through the whole dataframe. What if we assume there are more columns?

Comment: @VictorNielsen This looks through all columns but the first one. `df[-1]` removes the 1st column and keeps all others in a way that doesn't depend on the number of columns.

Comment: How would I specify the specific column names instead?

Comment: You would have to have a vector of column names or numbers and use `df[vec_of_cols]`. If there is a pattern in the column names, maybe `grep` could give you the vector.